# How to extract a large type with vs-code without the '... 19 more ...' truncate?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, types, ide

I have a large object (`pvtMsg`). vs-code shows a popup with the type when you hover over it. I would like to copy the entire type and paste it in another file. Then I would import that file in places where I want to use that type.

[image: screenshot of vs-code with large typescript object with a hover popup of the implicit type.]

The text is selectable, but the type is not complete, when I copy the text with `ctrl + a` the text `... 19 more ...` is copied. Is there a setting in vs-code to increase the maximum length before truncation?

[image: screenshot of the incomplete implicit type]

This issue also occures with `javascript` or `.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound unintuitive, but the [`noErrorTruncation`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noErrorTruncation) compiler option does not only control error messages, but also toggles truncation of type hints. If you set it to `true` in your tsconfig.json (or pass the equivalent CLI option), you will notice that the hints are no longer truncated.

For example, let's make an object `Test` with 35 properties. Here's how the hint looks like with `noErrorTruncation: false`:

[image: truncated type hint for an object with 35 properties]

And here is how it looks like with `noErrorTruncation: true`:

[image: full type hint for an object with 35 properties]

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7OJnN)

Note that there is a hard-coded [`absoluteMaximumLength`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b24b6a1125321fb62d53dd544a6c59f03a6eac07/src/services/utilities.ts#L2173) cutoff (calculated from [`defaultMaximumTruncationLength`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1e65b330a71cc09065b31f1724d78e931aafed51/src/compiler/utilities.ts#L7) to a total of 1600 chars ATTOW) at which point the display will be truncated regardless of whether the option is enabled or not.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was down-voted, it does work, but there can be more to it, especially if you're hitting the maximum length, see this open typescript git issue for more - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26238

Comment: Likely due to a well-known duplicate target existing, @chrismarx. My searching skills failed me for some reason that time - I decided to leave the answer hanging there as the question itself seems to be a "good duplicate". Might be a good idea to expand on it, will do so if I get enough time to spare.